# navbar collapses with smaller screen and leave affects expanding it back

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a complex scenario, please have a look at the below screenshots. 
[image: iamg 1]

When navbar is collapsed on the smaller screen, and I click on the button to expand, the following screen comes out, and it will go only if I click on any of the tabs( about, services etc), click on the top right icon for navbar, wont affect and the drop down menu does not go back.

The second scenario (please refer to the image below), when I expand the screen back from the smaller one, navbar is totally messed up. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Heres the css of my entire navbar.
[image: image 2]

CSS

```
.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #C57ED3;
  border: 1px solid #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white !important;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #C57ED3;
  border: 1px solid #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:visited {
  color: #C57ED3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #490D40;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  color: #C57ED3;
  background-color: #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse.collapse.in ul {
  background-color: #490D40;
}
```

html

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <img src="img/logo.png" width="130px;" height="50px;" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#abt">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services" >Services</a></li>


            <li><div class="dropdown" >
             <button class="dropbtn">Work</button>

            <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="web">Web Development</a>
    <a href="students">Students</a>
    <a href="writing">Content Writing</a>
  </div>
  </div>
          </li>



            <li><a href="#contact" >Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: where is the rest of your code?

Comment: I have updated, please have a look.

Comment: BS calls it toggler, not toggle, Also do you have all the js  at the bottom of your code before the closing </body> tag? Look at this page http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I tried. Heres my code tho. https://codepen.io/sonorangirl/pen/XmRBjq